# Creating enums having Key Value as string

Tags: c#, enums

I know following syntax is possible with enum, and one can get value by parsing it in int or char.

```
public enum Animal { Tiger=1, Lion=2 }
public enum Animal { Tiger='T', Lion='L' }
```

Although following syntax is also right

```
public enum Anumal { Tiger="TIG", Lion="LIO"}
```

How do I get the value in this case? If I convert it using `ToString()`, I get the KEY not the VALUE.

Comment: That String assignment syntax is _not_ right, and shouldn't compile.

Comment: { Tiger="TIG" will generate a *compile* time error

Comment: Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx  (The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.)

Comment: You might want to look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11130/String-Enumerations-in-C and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx

Comment: Don't forget whether you like it or not you will always have an Enum with a value of 0.

Comment: @CodeCamper: It is even "worse" than enums always having a zero value. Enum variables may be assigned *any* int value (if int is the underlying type of the enum). Just try: `int x = (new Random()).Next(); Animal an = (Animal)x; Console.Write(an); `

Comment: @morb That is great! So you can have 9 animals with random numbers. If none of those random numbers are 0 it will automatically create a 10th animal with the number 0 with no name however if one of the random numbers happens to be 0 then it will remain at 9 animals!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use strings in enums. Use one or multiple dictionaries istead:

```
Dictionary<Animal, String> Deers = new Dictionary<Animal, String>
{
    { Animal.Tiger, "TIG" },
    { ... }
};
```

Now you can get the string by using:

```
Console.WriteLine(Deers[Animal.Tiger]);
```

If your deer numbers are in line ( No gaps and starting at zero: 0, 1, 2, 3, ....) you could also use a array:

```
String[] Deers = new String[] { "TIG", "LIO" };
```

And use it this way:

```
Console.WriteLine(Deers[(int)Animal.Tiger]);
```

### Extension method

If you prefer not writing every time the code above every single time you could also use extension methods:

```
public static String AsString(this Animal value) => Deers.TryGetValue(value, out Animal result) ? result : null;
```

or if you use a simple array

```
public static String AsString(this Animal value)
{
    Int32 index = (Int32)value;
    return (index > -1 && index < Deers.Length) ? Deers[index] : null;
}
```

and use it this way:

```
Animal myAnimal = Animal.Tiger;
Console.WriteLine(myAnimal.AsString());
```

### Other possibilities

Its also possible to do the hole stuff by using reflection, but this depends how your performance should be ( see aiapatag's answer ).

Answer (score 10):

If you really insist on using `enum` to do this, you can do it by having a `Description` attribute and getting them via `Reflection`.

```
    public enum Animal
    {
        [Description("TIG")]
        Tiger,
        [Description("LIO")]
        Lion
    }

    public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes != null &&
            attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
```

Then get the value by `string description = GetEnumDescription(Animal.Tiger);`

Or by using **extension methods**:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetEnumDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes != null &&
            attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then use it by `string description = Animal.Lion.GetEnumDescription();`

Comment: Was going to offer same solution. Except, I suggest to make method GetEnumDescription extension

Comment: added the solution for the extension method as well. :)

Comment: @aiapatag this is a great solution. :D

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, the value of the enum *must* be mapped to a numeric data type. (`char` is actually a number wich is wirtten as a letter)
However one solution could be to have aliases with same value such as:

```
public enum Anumal { Tiger=1, TIG = 1, Lion= 2, LIO=2}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with Enums. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx
You can only parse INT Values back.

I would recommend static members:

```
public class Animal 
{
    public static string Tiger="TIG";
    public static string Lion="LIO";
}
```

I think it's easier to handle.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's a reason for why those are `enum`s

Comment: For sure, but is it clear and traceable code when i need a Reflection? - Just saying...

Answer (score 1):

As DonBoitnott said in comment, that should produce compile error. I just tried and it does produce. Enum is int type actually, and since char type is subset of int you can assign 'T' to enum but you cannot assign string to enum.

If you want to print 'T' of some number instead of Tiger, you just need to cast enum to that type.

```
((char)Animal.Tiger).ToString()
```

or

```
((int)Animal.Tiger).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternative solution:

```
public enum SexCode : byte { Male = 77, Female = 70 } // ascii values
```

after that, you can apply this trategy in your class

```
class contact {
    public SexCode sex {get; set;} // selected from enum
    public string sexST { get {((char)sex).ToString();}} // used in code
}
```